# What alternative to reflect.StructOf exists, prior to its addition to in 633ab74?

Tags: reflection, go, struct

I have some code that makes use of [`reflect.StructOf`](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf), which will presumably land in go1.7. Little did I know, that this wasn't available until only about 2 weeks ago, and only in current `master`. How does one create custom structs at runtime prior to this method being added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no way to create a new struct type at runtime prior to the addition of reflect.StructOf.

Comment: Can you provide a reference?